# java: cannot infer type arguments for MaxHeap<>

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, heap, max-heap

just running into some issues by making a heap. I have restricted bounds based on the interface I'm working with and i'm trying to access a constructor that efficiently adds a heap to demonstrate that the time complexity is reduced as opposed to adding a heap through insertion. In other words, I need this constructor to work but the driver program will not let me initialize the MaxHeapInterface object as an integer. Any thoughts?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public final class MaxHeap<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements 
MaxHeapInterface<T>
{
    private T[] heap;
    private int backIndex;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAP = 101;
    private static final int MAX_CAP = 101;
    private int efficientCounter=0;
    private int counter=0;

public MaxHeap()
{
    this(DEFAULT_CAP);
}

public MaxHeap(int chosenCap)
{
    if(chosenCap < DEFAULT_CAP )
        chosenCap = DEFAULT_CAP;
    else
        checkCapacity(chosenCap);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] holdHeap = (T[]) new Comparable[chosenCap +1];
    heap = holdHeap;
    backIndex = 0;
}
//efficient addition method-constructor
public MaxHeap(T[] entry)
{
    this(entry.length);

    for(int i =0; i < entry.length; i++)
        heap[i+1] = entry[i];
    for(int j = backIndex/2; j > 0; j-- )
    {
        reHeap(j);
    }
}
//other addition method
public void add(T entry)
{
    int index = backIndex+1;
    int halfIndex = index/2;
    counter++;
    while((halfIndex > 0) && entry.compareTo(heap[halfIndex])>0)
    {
        heap[index] = heap[halfIndex];
        index = halfIndex;
        halfIndex = index/2;
        counter++;
    }
    heap[index] = entry;
    backIndex++;

}
public T removeMax()
{
    T root = null;
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        root = heap[1];
        heap[1] = heap[backIndex];
        backIndex--;
        reHeap(1);
    }
    return root;
}

public T getMax()
{
    T root = null;
    if(!isEmpty())
        root = heap[1];
    return root;
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return backIndex < 1;
}

public int getSize()
{
    return backIndex;
}

public void clear()
{
    while(backIndex > -1)
    {
        heap[backIndex] = null;
        backIndex--;
    }
    backIndex = 0;
}
public int getEffcientcounter()
{
    return efficientCounter;
}

public int getCounter()
{
    return counter;
}
private void reHeap(int index)
{
    boolean done = false;
    T alone = heap[index];
    int leftChildLocation = 2*index;

    while(!done && (leftChildLocation <= backIndex))
    {
        int biggerChildLocation = leftChildLocation;
        int rightChildLocation = leftChildLocation +1;
        if((rightChildLocation <= backIndex)&& heap[rightChildLocation].compareTo(heap[biggerChildLocation])>0)
        {
            biggerChildLocation = rightChildLocation;
        }
        if(alone.compareTo(heap[biggerChildLocation])<0)
        {
            heap[index] = heap[biggerChildLocation];
            index = biggerChildLocation;
            leftChildLocation = index *2;
        }
        else{
            done = true;
        }
        heap[index] = alone;
    }
}

private void checkCapacity(int size)
{
    if(size>MAX_CAP)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Attempt to create a bag way too big." +
                "\n the limit is "+ MAX_CAP);
}
public void printHeap()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < heap.length; i++)
        System.out.print(heap[i]+"," +" ");
}
```

}

Here is a my driver which is unfortunately unfinished

```
import java.util.*;
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    boolean integerChecker = true;
    String input;
    int choice;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    MaxHeapInterface<Integer> randomHeap = new MaxHeap<>(101);
    MaxHeapInterface<Integer> sequentialHeap = new MaxHeap<>(101);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] array = new int[101];
    int[] array2 = new int[101];


    System.out.println("Please select how to test the program:");
    System.out.println("(1) 20 sets of 100 randomly generated integers");
    System.out.println("(2) Fixed Integer Values 1-100");
    System.out.print("Enter Choice: ");
    input = kb.next();
    kb.nextLine();
    integerChecker = isInteger(input);
    choice = Integer.parseInt(input);

    while(!integerChecker || choice<0 || choice >2)
    {
        System.out.println("Please input a valid choice: ");
        input = kb.next();
        kb.nextLine();
        integerChecker = isInteger(input);
        choice = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        list.add(i);


    if(choice == 1 )
    {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for(int i =1; i <100; i++)
        {
            randomHeap.add(list.get(i));
            array[i]= list.get(i);
        }
        //ERROR HERE
        MaxHeapInterface<Integer> betterRandomHeap = new MaxHeap<>(array);
        System.out.println("Average swaps for series of insertions");
        System.out.println("Average swaps for optimal method: ");

    }
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            sequentialHeap.add(i);
            array2[i]= list.get(i);
        }
        //ERROR HERE
        MaxHeapInterface<Integer> betterSequentialHeap= new MaxHeap<> 
        (array2);
        System.out.println("Heap built using series of insertions: ");
        sequentialHeap.printHeap();
        System.out.println("Number of swaps: ");
        System.out.println("Heap after 10 removals: ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Heap built using optimal method: ");
        betterSequentialHeap.printHeap();
        System.out.println("Number of swaps: ");
        System.out.println("Heap after 10 removals: ");


    }
}
private static boolean isInteger(String str)
{
    if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    int i = 0;
    if (str.charAt(0) == '-')
    {
        if (str.length() == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        i = 1;
    }
    for (i =0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Here is my interface

```
public interface MaxHeapInterface<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
{
    public void add(T entry);
    public T removeMax();
    public T getMax();
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public int getSize();
    public void clear();
    public void printHeap();
}
```

Comment: If possible can you put the complete code, since it is more of a stand alone java program. And BTW I don' see the constructor of MaxHeap with an array as argument.

Comment: Will do! i should have specified, The generic data type with (T[] entry) is the constructor for an array (well at least I think so)

Comment: What do you mean by `MaxHeapInterface<Array>` ?  You have no custom type called `Array`.

Comment: my apologies, I orgininally used Integer and must've made a mistake. Nontheless integer does not work at all

Answer (score 1):

Primitives and objects don't mix.  The issue lies here:

```
int array = new int[101];
int array2 = new int[101];
```

You can't pass in a primitive array when your method expects an object array, so simply change this to an object array instead.

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[101];
Integer[] array2 = new Integer[101];
```

Type inference can then continue.

Comment: Did you mean "Integer[] array = new Integer[101] " because that seemed to work, but thank you!

Comment: ...yes? I did mean that.